# how can i get the highest lowest and medium value from an array ..?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
[
0: {"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2596},
1: {"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": NaN},
2: {"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2864},
3: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 3000},
4: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 5500},
5: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 4500}
]
```

The above JSON value is not static. Sometimes it gets only two "value".  Get the lowest, highest, and medium values.

```
[
0: {"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2596},
1: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 3000},
2: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 5500},
]
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: You have a NaN in there.  Is that intentional?  Also that is _not_ JSON.  That is debugger variable display output.

Comment: do you mean median?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please

```js
var arr = [
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2596},
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": NaN},
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2864},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 3000},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 5500},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 4500}
], lowest, highest, medium, dump = [], i, x=0;

// Loop and save to dump to we can handle it
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    // If object not exists
    if(typeof arr[i].value == "undefined") continue;
    
    // Check the bad values
    if(null === arr[i].value || isNaN(arr[i].value) || false === arr[i].value || arr[i].value == undefined) continue;

    // Save to dump
    dump[x]=Number(arr[i].value);
    x++;
}

// Sort it
dump.sort();

// lowest
lowest = dump.shift();

// medium
medium = dump[Math.floor(dump.length / 2)];

// highest
highest = dump.pop();

console.log(lowest);
console.log(medium);
console.log(highest);
```

You must first convert your JSON to the correct array that JavaScript will accept. When you have it, you list all the values and take the results. You clear the array, sort from smaller to larger, and get the results you need.

Comment: Sorting it that way is a bit unnecessary. Plus OP wants the objects in the result set, not the values. To get that you'll have to write logic further.

Comment: Nice solution. Just one thing, the filtering and mapping of number part can be done using `map`. It will be just `dump = arr.map(({value})=>value).filter(Boolean).sort()`.

Comment: Why are you still using Math.max and Math.min if you sorted the array?  Just pop() and shift().  @ABGR 3000 is the median.  sort() is the simplest way to get the median, short of finding and implementing a median selection algorithm (eg one that is O(N)).

Comment: @gorak that could fail.  it will remove 0 values.  His filter is more correct.

Comment: @user120242, right, then we have to be specific `===NaN`. Good catch though. :)

Comment: @user120242 I was just saying getting all the values, then sorting them and then finding the right objects based on them could be a bit overhead when the sorting could be done right in the array of object based on the their value.

Comment: The title is "how could i get the highest lowest and medium value from an array" and I give him only values. I update my code but still staying behind it. It's basics and he can adapt it how he want. Answer from @ABGR is great solution to get object based result.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.

```js
var arr = [
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2596},
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": NaN},
{"carrier": "Spicejet", "value": 2864},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 3000},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 5500},
{"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 4500}
]

var filteredArr = arr.filter(i=> i.value && i.value!==0).sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value); //Remove falsy values except 0 and sort the array
const lowest  = filteredArr[0];
const highest = filteredArr[filteredArr.length-1];
const medium = filteredArr[Math.floor(filteredArr.length/2)]

   const res = [lowest, medium, highest];
   console.log(res)
```

Comment: this does not work correctly.  NaN is not handled properly.

Comment: @user120242 updted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array, that way the first element would become the smallest and the last will be the largest.

And by medium I take it that you want the average you can do that by adding all elements and dividing it by the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean exactly by medium ?

```js
const getMax = () => {
  let max = 0
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if ( !isNaN(x[i].value) && max < x[i].value) max = x[i].value
  }
  return max
}

const getMin = () => {
  let min = 0
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( !isNaN(x[i].value) && min > x[i].value) min = x[i].value
  }
  return min
}
```

Comment: average value .. [ 3: {"carrier": "Indigo", "value": 3000} ],

Comment: avrege = (min + max) / 2